# How can I use rest sharp to call this method

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, visual-studio-2012

I have a rest api defined as FruitFactory.svc,

```
  <%@ ServiceHost Debug="true" Language="C#" 
 Service="LocalFarm.WebServices.Internal.FruitFactory, 
 LocalFarm.WebServices.Internal, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=23j26b5f532c68dj" %>
```

web config is,

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Localfarm_BasicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Address is,

```
https://portal.localFarm.com/2240AM/136/_vti_bin/internal/fruitfactory.svc
```

How can I make a rest call to it using rest sharp api ?

```
[DataContract]
public class FileObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public string orderName;
    [DataMember]
    public byte[] data;
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IFruitFactory
{
    [OperationContract]
    FileObject[] GetInvoices(string customerID, string invoiceFolder, string customerName, string[] orderNames);
}
```

Tried this so far,

```
var client = new RestClient("https://portal.localFarm.com/2240AM/136/_vti_bin/internal/fruitfactory.svc");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");

var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
```

Not sure what to do next...

Comment: You should be able to "Add Service Reference" to your project. Assuming your .svc has defiend the mex.

Comment: OK, not sure if I follow, so the question is how to call .svc from C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created a WCF service, but this is not (necessarily) the same as a REST service. With your current configuration, your service is a SOAP service, which you are supposed to send messages to using a special XML format. The easiest way to communicate with it is to generate a service proxy, by right-clicking the "References"-entry in your project and then "Add service reference". This will create a service client which you can use to call methods on your service. The client handles conversion to the XML format used and such.

However, it is possible to make your service a REST/web service if you want to. There are two configuration changes and some code change required:

1. Reconfiguring the WCF `<bindings>`. Currently, you have `basicHttpBinding`, which as I mentioned is a SOAP 1.1 binding. There are a ton of bindings available ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731399(v=vs.110).aspx) is a listing from MSDN), one of which is the `webHttpBinding`.
2. Adding a [`WebHttp` behaviour](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) on the service so that your service's methods can be mapped to urls.
3. You'll need to add some information for mapping your `OperationContract` to a Url. This is done via the `WebInvoke` attribute.

Since I don't have your full `web.config` or application code, I'll attempt to illustrate these changes, but you may need to make some additional changes.

`web.config`:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="myBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors> <!-- Added webHttp behavior -->
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<services>
  <service name="LocalFarm.WebServices.Internal.FruitFactory"> <!-- Needs to match the Service name in the .svc file -->
    <endpoint address="" contract="LocalFarm.WebServices.Internal.IFruitFactory"
              binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Localfarm_WebHttpBinding" 
              behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Then in your code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFruitFactory
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "GetInvoices")]
    FileObject[] GetInvoices(string customerID, string invoiceFolder, string customerName, string[] orderNames);
}
```

This should allow you to make a GET request to `https://portal.localFarm.com/2240AM/136/_vti_bin/internal/fruitfactory.svc/GetInvoices?customerID=123&invoiceFolder=foo...etc...`. You might want to switch to POST for easier handling of arrays in this case, though.

Hope this helps, calling with RestSharp should work with the code you originally posted.

Comment: I didn't get chance to test your answer, but am accepting it for now, thanks